# Using gdal.Warp cutlineSQL option in python?

Tags: python, postgis, gdal

I want to use the `gdal.Warp` method with python ([doc](http://gdal.org/python/)). I have seen a `cutlineSQL` option which would be nice for my case since cutlines are stored in a PostGIS table but I can not find the syntax for this parameter.

How to tell gdal which database connection to use?

Or maybe I misunderstood the meaning of this parameter?

How to provide a cutline to `Warp` method then?

---

option not presented in [the warp tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/warptut.html) neither.

---

What I have so far :

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import GA_ReadOnly

# input dataset
dataset = gdal.OpenShared(path, GA_ReadOnly)
raster = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

# warp options
db_conn = """PG:"host=xx.xx.xx.xx port=5432 user='xxxx' password='xxxx' dbname='xxxx'" """
warp_opts = gdal.WarpOptions(
        format="GTiff",
        cutlineDSName=db_conn,
        cutlineSQL="SELECT cutline FROM table WHERE id_1",
        cropToCutline=True,
    )

# warp
res = gdal.Warp("test.tif",
                 raster,
                 options=warp_opts,
             )
```

Producing the error :

```
ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
invalid connection option ""host"

ERROR 1: Cannot open PG:"host=xx.xx.xx.xx port=5432 user='xxx' password=XXXXXXXXXX dbname='xxxx'" .
```

While ogrinfo with the same paramters is working.

If I try to remove some quotes in `db_conn` like this :

```
db_conn = "PG:host=xx.xx.xx.xx port=5432 user='xxxx' password='xxxx' dbname='xxxx'"
```

I end up with a seg fault...

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after a lot of efforts :-p, I ended up with a working script:

```
from osgeo import gdal

db_conn = "PG:host=xx.xx.xx.xx port=5432 user='xxxx' password='xxxx' dbname='xxxx'"
warp_opts = gdal.WarpOptions(
    format="GTiff",
    cutlineDSName=db_conn,
    cutlineSQL="SELECT cutline FROM table WHERE id=1",
    cropToCutline=True,
)

res = gdal.Warp("test.tif",
                 path,
                 options=warp_opts,
             )
```